# Regex - search string between /* and */ with separated lines

Tags: regex

I want make a regex what find newlines and string between "/*" and "*/" with newlines.

Actual:

- https://regex101.com/r/6E2KJQ/1
- Pattern:(\r\n|\r|\n)|(/*(?:*(?!/)|[^*])**/)

Test string:

```
/*SET end 
as alm
State ');*/
teszt
aa /*OPEN SorIDS;
  FETCH SorIDS INTO SorID;
  CLOSE SorIDS;*/
```

Result:

- Match 1 - Group 2. - 0-29
- Match 2 - Group 1. - 29-30
- Match 3 - Group 1. - 35-36
- Match 4 - Group 2. - 39-98

I want this result:

- Match 1 - Group 2. - 0-29
- -------------Group 3. - 10-11
- -------------Group 3. - 17-18
- Match 2 - Group 1. - 29-30
- Match 3 - Group 1. - 35-36
- Match 4 - Group 2. - 39-98
- -------------Group 3. - 53-54
- -------------Group 3. - 80-81

OR

- Match 1 - Group 2. - 0-10 (string to crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 10-11 (crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 11-17 (string to crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 17-18 (crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 18-29 (string to crlf)
- Match 2 - Group 1. - 29-30 (crlf)
- Match 3 - Group 1. - 35-36 (crlf)
- Match 4 - Group 2. - 39-53 (string to crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 53-54 (crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 54-80 (string to crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 80-81 (crlf)
- -------------Group ?. - 81-98 (string to crlf)

Comment: Write the pattern and the test string in the question, a simple link doesn't suffice and can eventually be broken in the future. Your question isn't well formatted, see: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. About your pattern: There is no group 3 in your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.
In a match on't get more than 1 result in same group.